# ElasticSearch Aggregating Against FIRST/Max Nested Document

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using Elastic Search trying to get an aggregation of "last login country" for a set of users, and am not sure whether ES supports this type of aggregation?  Here's a rough picture of the mapping:

```
User
   UserId
   Sessions (array)
     Session1 - CreateDate, Country
     Session2 - CreateDate, Country
```

What I'm wanting to do is pass in a date range, and get an output of the logins by country, with ONLY a single session per user.  In other words, if the user logged in 3 times during the date range, only 1 of those sessions would count towards the overall count.

The output would look something like the following:

```
Country Aggregations
   USA, Count: 10
   Japan, Count: 15
   Spain, Count: 23
```

I've been looking over nested aggregations, but I'm not sure they can give me what I need.  The main problem I'm having is that if a User has multiple Sessions during the date range, each of those sessions contribute to the overall country count.  Is there a way to filter this inner list of nested documents down so that only 1 will contribute to the aggregation per User?

Answer (score 1):

I posted this question on ElasticSearch's github forum, and apparently this functionality is not available in the current ES version (1.4.2):

https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/9536